# JQuery Mobile, redirecting by window.location prevents pageshow event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, window.location, pageshow

I have a JQuery Mobile application with many pages linked to each other.
If I put a link on page A and set the href to page B, this script works fine:

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#pageB',function(){
    alert('hello!');
});
```

But if I put a button on page A and write this code for onclick event:

```
window.location="pageB.html";
```

The pageshow event won't raise anymore!
Where's the problem? How can I use window.location and still be able to catch the pageshow event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `window.location` or `window.location.href`, you load pages normally without Ajax, and removes all previous pages in DOM.

If you have JS libraries loaded in *pageA.html*, they won't work when you load *pageB.html*, because they are removed.

Hence, you need to place JS libraries in *pageB.html*'s `<head>` to have JS code/libraries working.

---

### Update

Load pages / html files via Ajax using

```
// jQM 1.3.2 and below
$.mobile.changePage("#page_id" or "URL");

// jQM 1.4
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#page_id" or "URL");
```

Comment: thanks, actually I prefer to load pageB with Ajax. How is it possible to load another page with Ajax in click event of a button?

Comment: `$.mobile.changePage("#page or URL")`.